# Disassociating Notepad with Exe

Tags: windows-7, file-extension, notepad

I opened a program (.exe) with Microsoft's Notepad, just to see what would happen, and apparently all .exe files now open with Notepad. How do I fix this? Even explorer.exe now opens with Notepad. I am using a Windows 7 computer. I thought (using Task Manager) ending explore.exe and reopening it would fix it but since that opens with Notepad, it didn't. I only have a few programs open that were opened before I messed up, which is how I am able to ask this. Please help!

Comment: can you post an image of your registery at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe` with all nodes expanded?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: see several techniques here: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-or-restore-broken-exe-lnk-com-association-caused-by-virus/

Comment: I got explorer.exe back by typing explorer.exe in command prompt. So things are little better.

Comment: @FrankThomas one of the solutions found in that link worked. Thanks for the help